# Does Upgrading RAM automatically increases allocation to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, performancecounter

2 questions on RAM, Upgrade & SQL Server's usage -

1. Does upgrading RAM automatically increases the allocation to SQL Server or it has to be manually configured via `SP_CONFIGURE`?
2. Can we know what was originally allocated to SQL Server before configuring manually through `SP_CONFIGURE`? I could've found if I gathered the values from `SELECT object_name, cntr_value   FROM SYS.DM_OS_PERFORMANCE_COUNTERS WHERE counter_name IN ('Total Server Memory (KB)','Target Server Memory (KB)')` but I didn't.
   So, is there any way to find the historical config?

--In 'thoughts'...

Comment: While a specific answer would require knowing which version of SQL Server you're using, [this article](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/09/sysadmins-guide-microsoft-sql-server-memory/) gives it a pretty good treatment. TL; DR: "No matter how much memory you put in a system, SQL Server will use all it can get until it’s caching entire databases in memory and then some."

Comment: I was always under the impression that SQL Server would use all the RAM available to it by default, unless you specifically set a lower limit which is generally advised against

Comment: Why this question? Do you have an actual problem? You add RAM, SQL Server uses it unless you explicitly specified an upper limit. We can't know whether you did so or not. You can check that in SSMS, in the server's properties

Comment: Performance counters have nothing to do with this question either, nor with *configuration*. As the name says, those are Windows's performance counters

Comment: Adding more RAM does not "automatically" change any settings, including memory usage. By default, when it's installed, it is set to "infinite" *not actually infinite. If you set the max/min memory usage for the server, it will use the memory it requires up to those values. Assuming those amounts are actually available.

Comment: Thanks everyone for participating!
We've inherited a Server that has 24GB RAM but seeing Perf issues - low PLE values.  At last it is understood that Max Server Mem is set to a value which perhaps prevented from auto usage.
However, I would still want how Max Mem spec changed like we store historical data in OLTP systems to show the trends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the historical configuration values from any standard tables (apart from something pretty esoteric).

Whether or not SQL Server will automatically use all available memory just depends upon the max memory configuration. It's designed to use whatever memory is available, up to the configured maximum, apart from leaving some memory for the operating system.

If the operating system flags that it's running low on memory, SQL Server will release memory from its process when necessary. Usually it's pretty graceful, but the OS can also urgently require memory, and SQL Server will respond to that too. It starts dumping pages rapidly, and you'll usually see that in the SQL Server error log.

Comment: Thank you @Greg . Would you also post what type of SQL Server's `SYS.DM_OS_PERFORMANCE_COUNTERS` tell me Memory pressure from OS. I could dig these below - `"Checkpoint pages/sec", "Background writer pages/sec", "Pressure evictions (pages/sec)"`